# TSQL-Selecting a column but changing the display of that to a string of another query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to change the column name for displaying purposes. The column name will be based on whatever server and other column name combination I choose.

```
DECLARE
  @StartDate datetime,
  @EndDate datetime,
  @ServerId smallint,
   @string varchar

SET
  @StartDate =  DATEADD(HH,-1, @StartDate) 
SET
  @EndDate = GETDATE()
SET
  @ServerId = 1

set @string = (SELECT  ServerName,ServerPort from Server where ServerID = 50 )
select
    dl.DiagnosticCnt as @string, 
    dl.CreateDate  as time
from dbo.DiagnosticLog dl
    inner join dbo.Server s
    on dl.ServerID = s.ServerID AND s.ServerID = 50
    inner join dbo.Message m
    on dl.MessageID = m.MessageID 
WHERE  dl.MessageID = 8
ORDER BY time
```

so whatever that returns from `(SELECT  ServerName, ServerPort from Server where ServerID = 50 )` will be set to variable `@String` and I want that string to be the column name of  `dl.DiagnosticCnt`.

Comment: To do this would require dynamic sql. But you also have syntax error here. You are setting a scalar variable to the result of a query with two columns. This will fail. I would suggest that you don't want to change the name of your column dynamically like this. Instead consider adding two columns to the output for the server name and port.

Comment: How would I dynamically do this?I have to change the name of the column, not up to me. I guess pull the two values from 2 column, turn it into a string, and change the column name

Comment: I get you but I would push back on this requirement pretty hard. It is ill-advised to say the least. I have seen this type of thing requested by business before and when explaining that the point is to convey the information and the right way to do that is in the column they have always agreed it makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code, it uses dynamic SQL, the only way to perform such task. Necessary comments are in code:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime, @ServerId smallint, @string varchar(100)
--you can wrap it in one SELECT
SELECT @StartDate =  DATEADD(HH,-1, @StartDate), --here @StartDate is null and DATEADD will evalute to null as well !!
       @EndDate = GETDATE(),
       @ServerId = 1
--here you probably want to concatenate results, so you have to cast port number if it's not a varchar
SELECT @string = ServerName + CAST(ServerPort AS VARCHAR(20)) from Server where ServerID = 50
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX) =
'select
    dl.DiagnosticCnt as ' + QUOTENAME(@string) + ', 
    dl.CreateDate  as time
from dbo.DiagnosticLog dl
inner join dbo.Server s
    on dl.ServerID = s.ServerID AND s.ServerID = 50
inner join dbo.Message m
    on dl.MessageID = m.MessageID 
WHERE  dl.MessageID = 8
ORDER BY time'

EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: This is the only way I've seen this done is by using a concated query in a string provided to EXEC.  Keep in mind you need to be careful of the input when using dynamic SQL.

Comment: I would suggest wrapping your variable in QUOTENAME to prevent spaces or other characters that will cause this to fail. QUOTENAME(@string)

Comment: wow, awesome. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using a variable for the alias of a column can only be done with dynamic sql.